# Como restaurar posts con su 'post status' que tenía antes de ser movido a la papelera? - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Tengo un Custom post type en wordpress en cual al crear un post nuevo se crean 3 subposts hijos automáticamente. Por ejemplo creo el post y le asigno algún estado 'Publish', 'pending', 'draft' u otro:

- Post Company 1

  ```
   -Subpost 1 (se crea automaticamente)
   -Subpost 2 (se crea automaticamente)
   -Subpost 3 (se crea automaticamente)
  ```

Al eliminar el padre(se mueve a 'trash' ), se eliminarán también los subposts.
Pero al restaurarlos, deberán tener el **estado** con el que se habían guardado antes ('pending', 'draft', 'auto-draft' u otro).

**Cómo podría hacer eso de restaurar los post (padre e hijos) con su 'post-status' que tenían definido antes de ser movidos a 'trash'?**

Este es mi código que estoy utilizando para crear los 3 subposts hijos de manera automática:

```
function add_children_custom_post_type( $post_id ) {  
if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
    return;

if ( !wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) && 'companies' == get_post_type( $post_id ) && 'publish' == get_post_status( $post_id ) ) {  
    $show = get_post( $post_id );
    if( 0 == $show->post_parent ){
        $children =& get_children(
            array(
                'post_parent' => $post_id,
                'post_type' => 'companies'
            )
        );
        if( empty( $children ) ){
            //Children pages
            $titles = ['Subpost1', 'Subpost2', 'Subpost3'];
            foreach ($titles as $key=>$title) {
                $child = array(
                    'post_type' => 'companies',
                    'post_title' => $title,
                    'post_content' => '',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'post_parent' => $post_id,
                    'post_author' => get_post_field('post_author', $post_id),
                    'menu_order' => $key
                );
                wp_insert_post( $child );
            }
        }
     }
  }
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'add_children_custom_post_type' );
```

Y este es el que utilizo para mover los posts hijos de un post padre cuando se elimina el padre:

```
// Move to Trash
function trash_post_children($post_id) {
$parent_ID = $post_id;

$args =  array(
    'post_type' => 'companies',
    'post_parent' => $parent_ID,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'auto-draft', 'future', 'private', 'inherit', 'trash')
);
  $children = get_posts($args);
  if($children) {
      foreach($children as $p){
        wp_trash_post($p->ID, true);
      }
   }
}
add_action('trashed_post', 'trash_post_children');
```

Y este otro es para restaurar los posts pero se restauran siempre en estado 'draft':

```
// Restore Post
function restore_post_children($post_id) {
   $parent_ID = $post_id;
    $args =  array(
       'post_type' => 'companies',
       'post_parent' => $parent_ID,
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
       'post_status'    => 'trash'
   );
   $children = get_posts($args);
   if($children) {
    foreach($children as $p) {
        wp_untrash_post($p->ID);
    }
  }
}
add_action('untrash_post', 'restore_post_children');
```

Comment: En realidad no es posible, no puedes saber saber cual era su estatus anterior, existe un sistema interno llamada revisiones, nunca lo he usado pero puede que te sirva, fuera de eso lo que recomendaría seria tener un custom field asignado al post o un post meta donde guardes el ultimo estatus, de esa forma no tienes que adivinar el status anterior, solo lo recuperas porque previamente lo habías guardado. Al restaurarlos solo les pasas el Estatus anterior, ya que por defecto creo que pasan o a Publish o Draft

Comment: @JefferzonBol ok gracias... Creo que si se puede con `_wp_trash_meta_status` pero no estoy seguro de cómo aplicarlo :(

Answer (score 1):

Verificando bien si existe una forma, parece que WordPress Guarda un post_meta llamado "_wp_trash_meta_status" al que le debes de pasar el id del post

```
$status = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_trash_meta_status', true );
```

Solo necesitas el id del post y te retornara el status anterior, por lo que puedes ponerlo de nuevo con esto.

```
wp_untrash_post( $post_id );
```

Una vez retornado puedes actualizarlo con

```
$my_post = array(
      'ID'           => $post_id,
      'post_status'   => $status,
);
wp_update_post( $my_post );
```

Entonces obtienes el status anterior basado en su id, luego lo sacas del trash y después actualizas su status.

Por lo que quedaría algo así

```
// Restore Post
function restore_post_children($post_id) {
    
    $parent_ID = $post_id;
    $args =  array(
       'post_type' => 'companies',
       'post_parent' => $parent_ID,
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
       'post_status'    => 'trash'
   );
   $children = get_posts($args);
   if($children) {
    foreach($children as $p) {

         // Obtenemos el Status
         $status = get_post_meta( $p->ID, '_wp_trash_meta_status', true );

         // Lo sacamos del trash
         wp_untrash_post($p->ID);

         // Actualizamos el estado
         $my_post = array(
            'ID'           => $p->ID,
            'post_status'   => $status,
         );
         wp_update_post( $my_post );

    }
  }

}
add_action('untrash_post', 'restore_post_children');
```

**Edit**:

untrash_post Se activa antes de que se restaure una publicación desde la Papelera, por eso no se puede actualizar su status aun, por lo que lo mejor seria probar con esto.

```
function wp_restore_parent_post( $post_id, $previous_status ){
        
    $parent_post = array(
        'ID'           => $post_id,
        'post_status'   => $previous_status,
    );
    wp_update_post( $previous_status );
        
}
add_action( 'untrashed_post', 'wp_restore_parent_post' );
```

Ya que untrashed_post Se activa después de restaurar una publicación desde la Papelera.

Comment: Cómo lo puedo agregar a mi código que ya tengo? :(

Comment: Solo reemplaza la funcion restore_post_children() por el codigo que deje al final,

Comment: Funciona muy bien con los posts hijos, pero el post padre sigue teniendo el estado 'draft' al restaurarlo. :(

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta, revisa de nuevo la función restore_post_children()

Comment: Aún me sigue restaurando el post padre como 'draft'

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta, creo que tiene suficiente material para hacer sus pruebas, también recomiendo leer la documentación de wordpress para entenderlo mejor.

Comment: Esa ultima función `wp_restore_parent_post` debería ir debajo de la otra función que ya tenía?

Comment: Respuesta larga, si, respuesta corta, si, la plataforma me exije almenos 13 letras :v

Comment: ok. Me da este error al momento de restaurar: `ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function wp_restore_parent_post()`